# Securing website files from theft on Local server

Tags: php, security, obfuscation

Hello guys I need help to secure my laravel or core php website which runs on localhost on client's pc as per his demand now he wants to secure the website files from the given theft scenario.

**Scenario**

someone finds his system already login and he plugs in a pen drive and get all website files or the whole website directory from it.

**Solution to be applied**

a) Adding some sort of permission so that it cannot be copied to another destination like pen drive etc

**OR**

b) making a code unreadable for others much like javascript file compression.

Comment: "making a code unreadable for others much like javascript file compression", copy - uncompress - done.

Comment: Forbid (unknown or all) pen drives attach on system level. Set short console timeout and secure unlocking. Remove keyboard/mouse - webserver does not need in them.

Comment: Code obfuscation won't stop anyone from stealing or running the code since it's still valid. You can also always reverse it. Questions about securing servers (like stopping pen drives from copying files etc) isn't really about programming and thus off-topic here.

Comment: Trying to copy protect the code from the server actually sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you want to protect the code, make sure only the right people have access to the server in the first place. Exactly who are they afraid will copy the code, why would they and how?

Comment: Thank you guys for all your opinions really means alot, so basically we cannot secure the  files on the client's local server